# Discovering and configuring Si5332 via i2c

Tags: i2c

I would like to configure a Skyworks Si5332 via its i2c interface. At this time, the synthesizer IC is only available on an evaluation board, hence, I am using the Si5332-6EX-EVB. Datasheet [1](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/Skyworks/SL/documents/public/data-sheets/si5332-datasheet.pdf), reference manual [2](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/Skyworks/SL/documents/public/reference-manuals/si5332-rm.pdf), and schematic [3](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/SkyWorks/SL/documents/public/schematic-files/si5332-6ex-evb.zip) are available from Skyworks. The proprietary programmer for in-circuit programming is unavailable at this time. However, based on the documentation, bit-banging via i2c is possible.

Skyworks offers the software "ClockBuilder Pro" that can be used to program the registers via USB and MCU. The software also discloses the exact register settings that I need to send through i2c.

I added pullup resistors R118 and R119 and connect to SCL/SDA_3V3_DUT (and GND), cf. upper right corner of the schematic below.
[image: Page 9 of SI5332-6EX-EVB schematic]

So far so good. Now comes the confusing part and my question: **Once the ClockBuilder software starts and has detected the board, the Si5332 becomes visible on the i2c bus**, and I am able to set its registers directly via i2c. I am using a [I2CDriver](https://i2cdriver.com/) for this. The board remains visible even when I power-cycle the board. However, once I restart MSWindows or power the board off of an external supply, the Si5332 cannot be seen on the i2c bus. That is, the device does not respond when transactions are directed at its address.

**Has anyone seen such a behaviour with this or another product before?** What could be the cause for this, and how would I be able to access the Si5332 via i2c without having to run MSWindows and the ClockBuilder Pro software?

I have a total of three devices on the bus:

- I2CDriver (master in case of addressing Si5332, slave/invisible in monitoring mode)
- Si5332
- USB/MCU that is part of the Si5332 evaluation board (presumably the master)

By the way, I have reached out to the Skyworks support, but they refuse to talk to anyone non-corporate...

Comment: Please explain to me "...Si5332 cannot be seen on the i2c bus". Seen by what? Are there 3 devices on the bus or only two different software programs accessing the board via USB-I2C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in the manuals... turns out the USB-MCU controls a second, on-board I2C bus that is used to activate and configure voltage regulators.

Looking at Section 2, Power Supply Sequencing of [[2](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/Skyworks/SL/documents/public/reference-manuals/si5332-rm.pdf)], the Si5332 expects the voltages VDDA, VDD_DIG, and VDD_XTAL to be configured. The voltages can be enabled and set to 3.3V (the voltage of the i2c bus) using jumpers on the evaluation board. Once all three voltages are enabled, the Si5332-IC lights up on the i2c bus.